# How can I execute a python script as soon as there is a new commit on my gitlab repository?

Tags: python, gitlab

I have my source code hosted on gitlab repository, and I intend to run a python script if it detects any new push or commit in that gitlab repository. How can I catch this event ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger certain scripts when a commit occurs in the Gitlab repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652455/how-to-trigger-certain-scripts-when-a-commit-occurs-in-the-gitlab-repository)

Comment: In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file you need to add `'$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"` in rules in your yml file to capture the push or commit  to any branch and this will only trigger when push or commit happen to the branch mentioned here.In this Develop is the selected branch to trigger the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jenkins or AWS CodeStar to check for commits and then invoke your function inside Jenkins or AWS code build, or if you have a serverless function you can invoke it there. Setting a complete pipeline you will need some knowledge of CI/CD and DevOps. This is a pretty standard way of doing it.

A more get-around of doing this would be to use Gitlab API to check for commits every few minutes and invoke your code.